# PHP PDO class for rapid development

Tags: php, pdo

Can you recommend a PDO class which allows you to do something like these:

```
$db->insert('mytable', $array); 
$db->update('mytable', $array); 
$db->delete('mytable', $array);
```

With all the statements already "prepared/binded" internally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This wrapper class is pretty good: http://code.google.com/p/php-pdo-wrapper-class/

Example code:

```
$db->insert("mytable", array(
    "FName" => "John",
    "LName" => "Doe",
    "Age" => 26,
    "Gender" => "male"
));
```

Comment: This seems good enough, almost perfect for the job if not for the hard-coding of css file and HTML tags in it's error handling.

Answer (score 2):

Look into redbeanphp. Redbeanphp.com. It uses PDO as its back end and can do what you want.

Comment: I would consider this option in the future if I'll deal with ORM but for now I am more inclined with plain SQL.